# Powershell - Print the line if the 2 patterns are found

Tags: string, powershell, design-patterns

I have the following lines:

```
<option title="ORACLEDB" selected="selected" value="1111">ORACLEDB</option>
<option value=""  selected="selected"></option>
<option title="TRINITY" value="3162">TRINITY</option>
```

And I would need to print it ONLY if "option title" and "selected" are found.

When I use:

```
select-string -pattern "option title","selected" -Path "C:\Users\am281h\Desktop\page.htm" -AllMatches
```

Then it prints me ALL the lines matching either "option title " or "selected", when the result should be only that first line.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: `Select-String -Pattern` is RegEx based, so use one `Select-String -Pattern "option title.+selected"` the dot in a RegEx matches any character and the quantifier `+` means any number, but at least one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach to go through your file and search for patterns like this:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\am281h\Desktop\page.htm" | % { if ($_ -like "*option title*selected*"){Write-Host $_}}
```

`%` is an alias for foreach. Foreach gets its reference-object from the pipe.

`$_` addresses the current Object of the foreach.

`-like` lets you compare objects with simple patterns.

The `*` in `*option title*selected*` is equilavent of x-number of random characters (including 0 characters).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like xml nodes => I would process rows as xml parts:

```
$src = '<option title="ORACLEDB" selected="selected" value="1111">ORACLEDB</option>',
'<option value=""  selected="selected"></option>',
'<option title="TRINITY" value="3162">TRINITY</option>'

$src | 
  % {[xml]$_} | #its xml!
  ? { $_.option.title -and $_.option.selected } | #filter
  % { write-host $_.OuterXml } #print as text
```